# How can I exit this loop?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner and can't work out why this loop won't break.
I need to delete some users and for each user i'm prompted if i'm sure i want to delete the user.
so i made the following loop:

```
while (!alert && delete_button_is_present)
{
    clickDeleteBtn;

    if(alert)
    {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    }

    else if(delete_button_is_not_present)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Problem is after all users are deleted and delete button is not present anymore  the test is still looking for the button.

Comment: Nothing is updating delete_button_is_present in your loop.

Comment: is the `if` block for the `else if` block in your code?

Comment: that code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Lets walk through your code

```
while (!alert && delete_button_is_present)
    {
    clickDeleteBtn;

    if(alert)
    {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

        else if(delete_button_is_not_present)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

You're saying that you want to continue this loop as long as there is no alert, and there is a delete button present on the screen. First, you click the delete button. Without any information about what this button does, I'll assume it is not relevant to the loop. You say `if(alert)`, but if there was an alert you wouldn't be in the loop in the first place...So the loop repeats

Comment: The loop apparently works(x button is clicked and the prompt following it is closed then moves on to the next user) up until the delete button is no longer present on the page , after that i get the NoSuchElementException : unable to locate element "delete button". What i need is for my loop to stop when the delete button is no longer present on page.

Comment: If sounds like you remove the delete button after the loop has already started. We'd need to see the rest of your code to fix the logic. Alternatively, you could just place the clickDeleteBtn; inside an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure delete_button_is_present is or at least can be modified in either clickDeleteButton or driver.switchTo().alert().accept(), or that condition can never be met.

Some questions I have about your code though, which might help if they get cleaned up: you have delete_button_is_present and delete_button_is_not_present.  You can get rid of not_present and just use !delete_button_is_present.  Why do you have an else if which isn't paired with an if inside if(alert)?  If you mean for this to be if(alert), then if(!delete_button_present) then you just need an if statement.  Otherwise you want that else if outside the if(alert).